# In ASP Classic, can I have a script close the HTTP connection and continue executing?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a script that occasionally needs to do some time-consuming (15s) background processing, but other times it is a simple redirect. The redirect target is known early on in the script's execution. Is it possible to, once the redirect URL is known, send the redirect HTML to the user agent and close the HTTP response, but continue processing the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this by executing a program (BAT, EXE, etc) asynchronously from the ASP code.

```
    set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    runcmd = "c:\myOwnProgram.bat param1=test"
    wshell.run runcmd, 0, False
```

`Wshell.Run` lets you run stuff async.  So fire away your timeconsuming tasks without worrying about script timeouts! Really great.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll give that a go. I can split the script into two, and use wshell to call wget to execute the second part of the script. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have tried that but I get a permissions error: `Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied`

Comment: make sure the application pool have access to the program your trying to execute. Normally the IIS is running as "Local_service", but it could run under another account. 1. Check which account the IIS pool is running as. 2. Right-klick your program file and add the required priviligies.

Comment: Important: Take care in securing all input before executing files on the server, as this solution could result in a big security hole.

Comment: Hi David, I have assigned the Local_service user full perms on both the file and the dir it is in, but still get the same error. The Applocation pool is running as Network Service according to IIS Manager. I tried giving the file/dir perms to ASPNET,  IIS_WPG, Internet Guest Acct, Launch IIS Process Acct, NETWORK, NETWORK_SERVICE, and SYSTEM as well - but still no luck. Any Ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: See http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html

Comment: Not only do the app.pool account require permission to your program, but also to files that your program will access. Example: If your program (c:\MyOwnProgram.bat) writes to a file in D:\temp, you will need to give NetworkService write permisson to D:\Temp as well (and perhaps subfolders/files).

Comment: final thought. For testing puposes (and only that!) you can change the app.pool account to "localSystem". This will give unlimited superpowers to the IIS. Under these circumstances you should not experience any permission problems. Good luck!  :)